# How to grab a container when wrapping render call into act?

Tags: react-testing-library, testing-library

`render` utility of React Testing Library among other things returns a `container`, that can be used to [manually query](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#manual-queries) the constructed DOM snippet. However when render call is wrapped into an `act` [utility](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/installation#act) (to avoid dreadful `When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...)` warnings), return value is `undefined`. I find this not intuitive. Is it expected? How would one gain access to the `container` (and other utilities) when using `act`?

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access all the destructured values by declaring them as a `let` variable outside your test and then using them in your render statement:

```
let debug;
let container;

it('renders', async () => {
    await act( async () => ({ container, debug } = render(<MyComponent />)));
    debug(container);
});
```

Comment: Interesting. However it sucks that act doesn't simply pass on the return value.